# Creating 1-D random walks to have lengths equal to some observed distribution of path lengths.

Tags: probability, random-walk

Given a population of vectors with lengths drawn from a normal distribution with a mean of 60, and variance of 30 (for example), how can I create a 1-D random walk with some ending probability *p* at each step, so that generated random walks will have a length equivalent to those from the observed distribution?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you have a finite or infinite number of vectors? What do you mean by "create a random walk"? What is the "observed distribution"? If you can write these out mathematically, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Maybe a better way of phrasing this: Given a normal distribution representing the length of a finite set vectors, I wish to create a 1d random walk with some ending probability at each step, so that the resulting random walk has a length which could be drawn from the original normal distribution. Specifically so that if I generate a large number of such walks, I can recover the original distribution.

Comment: Sorry - I'm not entirely sure how to write this all out mathematically